# PERC H710p SMART data

Tags: smart, dell-perc, drac

I'm trying to read the SMART data from some harddisks attached to a perc H710p but neither ESXI nor the idrac7 will give me specifics. The idrac will display a status for the individual drives but not the actual smart values.

Does anyone know how I can get this data?

Comment: Why do you need SMART values? The RAID controller uses that along with other parameters to determine drive health. Trust it!

Comment: We have a few SSDs and would like to monitor there health more closely so we can more accurately predict there lifespan, what we don't want is just an alert one morning indicating a bunch of disks are about to die.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use the smartctl utilities you can query a drive behind an [HP](https://serverfault.com/a/532413/2101) or Dell perc (MegaRAID) controller:

```
smartctl -l ssd -d megaraid,0 /dev/sda
```

and graph that using your monitoring tool to extrapolate when a drive is going to run out of wear levelling space:

[image: wear level graph]

Too bad you're on ESXi.

If you can't read that directly, wait for drive to throw out a SMART alert - that'll happen *before* it runs out.