# Consumer HDDs in a HP ProLiant DL180 G6?

Tags: hard-drive, hp, hp-proliant

Model: HP ProLiant DL180 507168-B21

Will a ProLiant DL180 G6 work with a single 1TB consumer hard drive in a caddy?
Yes, I know I should use enterprise HDDs but we have a limited budget, and this server will be used for testing, not any critical operations.

If the above stated configuration won't work, what will be the cheapest configuration I can do?

Note: I am prepared to lose data on this drive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this will work.

Normally, I steer people away from cheap disks, but this is a cheap server and is particularly suited to being stuffed with cheap disks (versus other ProLiant models).

The [HP ProLiant DL180 G6](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/productbulletin.html#spectype=north_america&type=html&docid=13248) model you list is an 8-bay unit. The backplane is a hotplug backplane.

Depending on your controller setup, you can use whatever 3.5" SAS or SATA disk you wish in the system. This server may have an HP Smart Array P410 controller or a handful of SATA leads to the motherboard. Can you clarify what you have, because the part number you listed is just the chassis.

Comment: According to the listing "Raid Controller: P410"

Comment: Yeah, you're fine. Anything will work. Keep in mind that SATA drives will only [operate at 3Gbps speeds](http://serverfault.com/questions/531499/3rd-party-ssd-drive-in-hp-proliant-server-only-shows-3g-transfer-speed) on that controller.