# Samsung 850 EVO + HP P410 limited iops?

Tags: linux, raid, performance, ssd, hp-smart-array

I´m experiencing a weird write iops limitation with a HP P410 256mb cache controller and 4x consumer grade ssd´s (Samsung EVO 850) in RAID5/10. After upgrade to latest firmware (6.64) for HP P410 controller, it continues with problems.

Iostat output:

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00    1.00  158.00    36.00 15631.00   197.07    12.16   75.84    6.00   76.28   6.30 100.10

158 writes/s and 100 % util.
```

My hpacucli output:

```
=> ctrl all show config detail

Smart Array P410 in Slot 2
   Bus Interface: PCI
   Slot: 2
   Serial Number: PACCR9SYLZ34
   Cache Serial Number: PACCQ9SYP5CK
   RAID 6 (ADG) Status: Disabled
   Controller Status: OK
   Hardware Revision: C
   Firmware Version: 6.62
   Rebuild Priority: Medium
   Expand Priority: Medium
   Surface Scan Delay: 15 secs
   Surface Scan Mode: Idle
   Queue Depth: Automatic
   Monitor and Performance Delay: 60  min
   Elevator Sort: Enabled
   Degraded Performance Optimization: Disabled
   Inconsistency Repair Policy: Disabled
   Wait for Cache Room: Disabled
   Surface Analysis Inconsistency Notification: Disabled
   Post Prompt Timeout: 0 secs
   Cache Board Present: True
   Cache Status: OK
   Cache Ratio: 100% Read / 0% Write
   Drive Write Cache: Disabled
   Total Cache Size: 256 MB
   Total Cache Memory Available: 144 MB
   No-Battery Write Cache: Disabled
   Battery/Capacitor Count: 0
   SATA NCQ Supported: True

   Array: A
      Interface Type: Solid State SATA
      Unused Space: 0  MB
      Status: OK
      Array Type: Data



      Logical Drive: 1
         Size: 698.6 GB
         Fault Tolerance: RAID 5
         Heads: 255
         Sectors Per Track: 32
         Cylinders: 65535
         Strip Size: 256 KB
         Full Stripe Size: 768 KB
         Status: OK
         Caching:  Enabled
         Parity Initialization Status: Initialization Failed
         Unique Identifier: 600508B1001C8929D0C6820FB103773E
         Disk Name: /dev/sda
         Mount Points: None
         Logical Drive Label: A516FD0DPACCR9SYLZ3435C0
         Drive Type: Data

      physicaldrive 1I:1:1
         Port: 1I
         Box: 1
         Bay: 1
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: Solid State SATA
         Size: 250 GB
         Firmware Revision: EMT01B6Q
         Serial Number: S21PNSAG270000F     
         Model: ATA     Samsung SSD 850 
         SATA NCQ Capable: True
         SATA NCQ Enabled: True
         Current Temperature (C): 30
         Maximum Temperature (C): 70
         SSD Smart Trip Wearout: Not Supported
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 3.0Gbps

      physicaldrive 1I:1:2
         Port: 1I
         Box: 1
         Bay: 2
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: Solid State SATA
         Size: 250 GB
         Firmware Revision: EMT01B6Q
         Serial Number: S21PNSAG269993V     
         Model: ATA     Samsung SSD 850 
         SATA NCQ Capable: True
         SATA NCQ Enabled: True
         Current Temperature (C): 32
         Maximum Temperature (C): 70
         SSD Smart Trip Wearout: Not Supported
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 3.0Gbps

      physicaldrive 1I:1:3
         Port: 1I
         Box: 1
         Bay: 3
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: Solid State SATA
         Size: 250 GB
         Firmware Revision: EMT01B6Q
         Serial Number: S21PNSAG269984Z     
         Model: ATA     Samsung SSD 850 
         SATA NCQ Capable: True
         SATA NCQ Enabled: True
         Current Temperature (C): 31
         Maximum Temperature (C): 70
         SSD Smart Trip Wearout: Not Supported
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 3.0Gbps

      physicaldrive 1I:1:4
         Port: 1I
         Box: 1
         Bay: 4
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: Solid State SATA
         Size: 250 GB
         Firmware Revision: EMT01B6Q
         Serial Number: S21PNSAG269998N     
         Model: ATA     Samsung SSD 850 
         SATA NCQ Capable: True
         SATA NCQ Enabled: True
         Current Temperature (C): 31
         Maximum Temperature (C): 70
         SSD Smart Trip Wearout: Not Supported
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 3.0Gbps


   SEP (Vendor ID PMCSIERA, Model  SRC 8x6G) 250
      Device Number: 250
      Firmware Version: RevC
      WWID: 500143800694906F
      Vendor ID: PMCSIERA
      Model:  SRC 8x6G
```

Someone has experienced this problem with HP P410?

Comment: Can you show us how you're testing the I/O performance of the array?

Comment: thank you ewwhite. To be honest, i´m not using iozone, dd, bonnie or other tools, i setuped 4-5 vm for testing performance and with a "normal" workload it tops at 200-250 writes/s. Altough i´m not using cache or other things, i guess that at least 1000-2000 iops for ssd setup must be reached.

Comment: I´,m feeling stupid but the problem was caused because bios smarta array dont let define parameters in the creation of the arrays, so were configured incorrectly two options, caching=disabled in the logical drive and non-battery write cache also disabled... Thanks to both answers, i appreciate really it.

Comment: In case others are looking for possible SSD+410i compatibility-- I tried using a Samsung 850 EVO in an HP DL360 G6 using the P410i firmware 2.50 (final release for the G6) and got nothing but the dreaded orange light from the RAID controller.

Comment: 2.50 might not be the final release-- checking if an update might help with this.

Comment: 2 hours later... indeed even though I had auto-updated the firmware via SPP on this server, the SmartArray firmware wasn't *actually* updated. After updating it to 6.64, I no longer get the Orange Light of Drive Rejection and the Samsung EVO 850 SSD is seen by the controller. For details about my adventure in Firmware Updates see: https://serverfault.com/questions/912858/how-can-i-update-the-smartarray-p410i-firmware-on-a-dl360g6-the-usual-method-vi

Answer (score 8):

There are a few issues here.

- You don't have any controller write cache or a battery-backed or flash-capacitor.
- The HP Smart Array P410 controller is limited in IOPS capacity. It's not a good match for SSDs.
- Using SATA drives on a Smart Array P410 causes the [interface speed to downshift](https://serverfault.com/questions/531499/3rd-party-ssd-drive-in-hp-proliant-server-only-shows-3g-transfer-speed) to 3.0Gbps instead of 6.0Gbps.
- Please try with RAID 1+0. RAID5 is not good for this combination of equipment.
- Also, your [RAID5 parity initialization failed](https://serverfault.com/questions/435726/hp-acu-shows-parity-initialization-failed-on-smart-array-controller/435775#435775), according to your `hpssacli` output.

> ```
>      Parity Initialization Status: Initialization Failed
> ```

HP's [best practices for SSDs](http://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=3902574&calledBy=&ac.admitted=1385472178235.876444892.199480143&docId=emr_na-c02963968-2&docLocale=) on that controller are listed [here](http://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=3902574&calledBy=&ac.admitted=1385472178235.876444892.199480143&docId=emr_na-c02963968-2&docLocale=).

Also see: [SSD (Intel 530) read/write speed very slow with RAID 10](https://serverfault.com/questions/557509/ssd-intel-530-read-write-speed-very-slow-with-raid-10) and [HP ACU shows parity initialization failed on Smart Array controller](https://serverfault.com/questions/435726/hp-acu-shows-parity-initialization-failed-on-smart-array-controller/435775#435775)

Answer (score 3):

MLC SSD really need a fast private DRAM cache for delivering high IOPS values.

While your controller has its own cache and it is enabled, your disk's private DRAM cache is disabled. This is a safety measure, as enabling that unprotected (from power losses) cache can put your data at risk.

Sometime it is safe to reenable it (eg: your disks has power loss protection, or your controller correctly propagate ATA FLUSH / FUA commands to the downstream disks), but you can't be 100% sure without testing. Some RAID controller even do not permit to reenable the disk's private DRAM cache.

For testing purpose, you can try to reenable it and re-test your array, but be very careful to put it into production. When possible, use SSD with power loss protection (Crucial M550/M600 have a partial protection, while Intel S3500/3700/DC series have *full* power protection).