# Can I Use a Normal SSD disk in HP DL380 G6

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, ssd, hp-smart-array, sata

We have a bunch of DL-380 G6 servers in our company, I want to know whether it is possible to use 2.5" SSD hard drives (with SATA III interface) on these servers or not?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't just use any SSD in that model server.

The Smart Array P410 array controller is a little sensitive, but will work with *most* SSDs. For others, it may not recognize the disks or will show error lights or even cause the system fan speeds to increase (because of misread SSD temperature sensors).

**Being more specific about which SSDs you'd like to use would be helpful.**

But another consideration is that SATA disks on that controller will be downshifted to 3.0Gbps speeds instead of 6.0Gbps. Also, the [controller has an IOPS limit of ~50,000](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=3902574&calledBy=&ac.admitted=1385472178235.876444892.199480143&docId=emr_na-c02963968-2&docLocale=), so there's a performance ceiling of ~6 disks.

Please see: [Samsung 850 EVO + HP P410 limited iops?](https://serverfault.com/questions/685103/samsung-850-evo-hp-p410-limited-iops/685106#685106)