# HP DL580 HDD Fan Issue

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, sata

I recently obtained an HP ProLiant DL580 G7 without any HDDs so I went ahead and installed an SSD which works great and the other day I ordered a 2.5" SATA 2 TB HDD (ST2000LMB15).

After installing the new SATA drive, one of the temperature sensors on the servers (sensor 17) has seemingly jumped up to 47 degrees Celsius, the exact temperature necessary for the fans to increase their speed in an endless cycle until they hit their maximum speed (this is loud, WAY too loud!).

After removing the drive, the sensor magically returns to its normal 35 degrees Celsius temperature and the fan speeds begin to return to their normal speeds.

I have found a [thread](https://community.hpe.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-ML-DL-SL/DL580-G7-overheat-temperature-sensor-17/m-p/6912986/highlight/true#M155369) where two different people seem to run into this same issue but no solution was ever posted. At this point, I'm assuming that the HDD is reporting incompatible or incorrect data to the server and ultimately causing this annoying issue.

Right now, the only solution I see is to replace the drive with an enterprise SAS drive, but I wanted to check with the people here first to see if anyone has experienced this issue (or anything similar) before. [This](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00512JC5G) is the drive I'm considering replacing it with.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use non-HP SATA drives in HP ProLiant servers.

See: [Can I Use a Normal SSD disk in HP DL380 G6](https://serverfault.com/questions/688730/can-i-use-a-normal-ssd-disk-in-hp-dl380-g6/688733#688733)

> The Smart Array P410 array controller is a little sensitive, but will
>   work with most SSDs. For others, it may not recognize the disks or
>   will show error lights or even cause the system fan speeds to increase
>   (because of misread SSD temperature sensors).

I don't know where you are located, but you can find proper HP disks for this generation of server for [very low prices](http://www.ebay.com/sch/m.html?_odkw=hp%206g&_ssn=crowntechsolutions&_armrs=1&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=hp&_sacat=0). Please do that and use a supported solution.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid further issues I'd recommend using HP supported drives is possible: 
[HP ProLiant DL580 G7 Server - Option Parts - Drives](http://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docLocale=en_US&docId=emr_na-c02826607&sp4ts.oid=89018#N1041F)