# HP ProLiant DL360 G6 RAID rebuild fan noise

Tags: raid, hard-drive, hardware, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I needed to expand the size of the shared drive on my HP ProLiant DL360 G6. I purchased two hard drives, replaced the first one and expected the computer to rebuild the RAID. The fans kicked in to full speed and I assumed the computer working.

I did not know how to check on the progress of the RAID, so I let it run for about 5 hours. No knowing what was going on I shut the computer down and booted into the HP Smart start utility disc. There I could see that the RAID was still rebuilding.

However, I only had 12 GB of data on the drive that I had backed up and figured it be faster to delete the logical drive and start over. Therefore, I did that. I put both of the new drives in and created a new RAID 2 logical drive. It has been more than 10 hours since I built the new drive and the fans have not stopped spinning at full speed. How do I get the fans to spin normally?

One other thing, the drives are made by HGST and are physically half as thick as the ones I pulled out. It thought that was odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these HP drives?
Please provide the specific make and model of disks you installed in the system

If they are not HP drives, you've my have caused trouble by installing incompatible equipment.

See: [Can I Use a Normal SSD disk in HP DL380 G6](https://serverfault.com/questions/688730/can-i-use-a-normal-ssd-disk-in-hp-dl380-g6/688733#688733)

---

Basically, you're using low-cost laptop hard disks in your server!!

This is a bad idea. The SmartArray P410 controller won't be able to read the temperature and the system fans will spin at a higher RPM to compensate.

[image]

Also, since these are SATA, the link speed on the controller will downshift to 3.0Gbps or lower.

A [proper HP disk in 300GB capacity](http://www.ebay.com/itm/HP-507127-B21-300GB-10K-6G-2-5-SAS-DUAL-PORT-HDD-/170577592050?hash=item27b7377ef2:m:mMA3vZuREzCNYM62vzQE7Sg) is $50. Do that instead.

Comment: They are HGST Travelstar SATA III 500GB 7,200 RPM. http://www.microcenter.com/product/475176/Travelstar_SATA_III_500GB_7,200_RPM_25_Internal_Notebook_Hard_Drive_(Factory-Recertified)

Comment: You should use HP disks instead. Sorry, but these will not be healthy for your server or controller.

Comment: "you're using low-cost laptop hard disks in your server!!" Right, bad idea. Thanks for the help. I'll get some real drives.