# How can I update the SmartArray P410i firmware on a DL360G6? The usual method via SPP Auto-Update fails

Tags: hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

Usually this works great-- boot from the SPP ISO, walk away for a beverage, come back and everything's updated. Not so on a few of my servers...

The final SPP release for these old DL360 G6 servers was Oct 2016, so that's what I'm using. Here's what I see during the automatic update process:

[image: Deployment Log showing "no devices updated"]

So far I've tried to update it from the OS (ESXi 5.5) using the downloaded standalone driver from HP (which has ESXi 5.5 listed as a supported OS) but that process fails with issues like:

```
# cd /tmp/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hp-firmware-smartarray-14ef73e580-6.64-2
# ./hpsetup
./hpsetup: line 226: tr: not found
./hpsetup: line 226: tr: not found
./hpsetup: line 226: tr: not found
./hpsetup: line 226: tr: not found
./hpsetup: line 226: tr: not found
./hpsetup: line 293: syntax error: bad substitution
```

Running the raw .scexe has similar issues. Clearly a case of the OS not supporting the patch script.

I found this article which coincidentally has my identical starting firmware version (2.50) so I'm wondering if perhaps there's a bad version out there that breaks future automatic updates (fun!) https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=13184

Based on that, I plan to try and find a live CD that will work for this HP firmware update. Has anyone found one that works well for this process? Alternatively, **is there a way to get the SPP update process to work correctly?** (I would expect that boot environment to be VERY HP-firmware-update-friendly, yet in this case it seems to not work properly.)

Answer (score 3):

I found something that worked on only the second try.

### First try: system rescue CD

This fails due to fundamental kernel incompatibilities with the HP-provided binaries. That's not surprising since it uses a Linux kernel version 4 and the HP binaries are for version 2.

### Second try: CentOS 6 rescue mode

This sort of worked. In order to make it work, I needed to copy the `dirname` and `tr` binaries from another preinstalled CentOS 6 server. There did not seem to be any way to add binaries to the rescue environment since it's mounted read-only as a loop device from an image in /tmp.

However, I could copy compatible binaries into /tmp and then add /tmp to my PATH.

On "centos6" existing host:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ <upload hp-firmware-smartarray-14ef73e580-6.64-2.x86_64.rpm here>
$ rpm2cpio hp-firmware-smartarray-14ef73e580-6.64-2.x86_64.rpm | cpio -id
31207 blocks
```

Here's what was done to make this work on the DL360G6 after booting CentOS6 into rescue mode, enabling network, and dropping to a rescue shell without attempting to mount any existing linux installations:

```
# scp user@centos6:/usr/bin/dirname /tmp/.
# scp user@centos6:/usr/bin/tr /tmp/.
# scp -rp user@centos6:/tmp/usr /tmp/.
# export PATH=$PATH:/tmp
# which tr
/tmp/tr
# cd /tmp/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hp-firmware-smartarray-14ef73e580-6.64-2
# ./hpsetup
```

Magic! It works!
[image: CentOS 6 Rescue Mode as a Live CD with adjustments allowed update to work]

Also confirmed from the ESXi 5.5 ssh CLI:

```
~ # esxcli hpssacli cmd --cmdopts="ctrl all show config detail"

Smart Array P410i in Slot 0 (Embedded)
  Bus Interface: PCI
  Slot: 0
  ...
  RAID 6 (ADG) Status: Disabled
  Controller Status: OK
  Hardware Revision: C
  Firmware Version: 6.64
```

Firmware Version: 6.64... nice!

Comment: I was able to get this working with Fedora 29 rescue mode quite easily. After running the rpm2cpio command on the file straight on my boot drive, I simply navigated to /run/install/repo/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hp-firmware* and ran the hp setup from there. I did not require SCPing binaries or playing with PATH.

Comment: Thanks for trying that out! It's nice to know there's a compatible rescue environment out there which includes "tr" by default.

Comment: Yes it works.
I had the same problem on the DL360 G7 P410i.
After an unsuccessful update, I could not configure the raid at all!
Thank.
[Instructions in Russian](https://blog.volobuev.su/obnovlenie-proshivki-hp-smart-array-p410i-s-versii-2-50-do-6-64b/comment-page-1/?unapproved=25799&moderation-hash=64358d40cca771e4fe54f1e414ba0e00#comment-25799)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem updating my HP Proliant DL380 G7 with a P410i raid card.  Posting to help others.

When I ran hpsetup the error was "310: Bad Substitution"

My solution was to run ccissflash instead of hpsetup. It worked perfectly.

I did this under Linux Mint 20.1 x64
used firmware:
Version:    6.64 (B)(1 Oct 2015)
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (AMD64/EM64T)
firmware-smartarray-14ef73e580-6.64-2.x86_64.rpm