# Cannot find any documentation for ORCA updates

Tags: hp, update

I need to update my ORCA to the latest version on both of my DL380 G7s. I am aware they are out of date, but they are good enough for my purpose. Can someone direct me to where I can find the correct documentation for updating ORCA to the latest version? I've tried multiple different files from HP, but none of them seem to want to boot from a USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found the answer to all this.

You have to install the Service Pack for Proliant (SPP).

Sadly you have to pay but you can search for hte SHA256 Hashes and find a free download. Make sure you check the hashes are the same for each file because you may accidently download a virus.

Answer (score 1):

DL380G7, unless otherwise equipped with add-on stuff, hosts P410i SAS controller onboard. For that beast the latest and greatest firmware was 6.64B released back in 2015 and available at the time of this writing [here](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/swd/detail?swItemId=MTX_5e52f965d84f41c2bb65d33b58).

Regardless of version you're currently using, the proper update procedure is to boot the machine off a Linux Mint 20.1 x64 ISO, download firmware mentioned above, extract it and run `ccissflash` from the location of the extracted firmware files as documented [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/912858/how-can-i-update-the-smartarray-p410i-firmware-on-a-dl360g6-the-usual-method-vi).